# Encoding issue with MultipartFile

Tags: spring, multifile-uploader

I am having some kinda encoding issue with the MultipartFile. My fileName contains double quote " and Left/right single quotes, and somehow those chars are being replaced with space... I am having issue trying to validate the file name to check against these chars because it is getting replace with space. Also, when printing/ displaying [file.getOriginalFilename()] those chars are now replaced with ?.

I have tried to convert the multipartFile to a standard java.io.file so I cant read the file property and same issue. :(

any help would be gladly appreciated.

Thanks.
Korda

Comment: Looks like this little hack did the work :)

Comment: fileName = new String (documentToUpload.getLatestVersion().getAttachmentFileName().getBytes (), "iso-8859-1");